# how to get an array of sqlite select results in C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Hi I'm trying to get values returned from sqlite, but currently I'm having a problem getting a whole array of list.

this is what I made so far:

```
private IDataReader _reader = null;
public void DB_Load_test ( )
{
    _connection = new SqliteConnection ( _sqlDBLocation );
    _command = _connection.CreateCommand ( );
    _connection.Open ( );
    _command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM some_table"; 

    _reader = _command.ExecuteReader ( );

}
```

the `_reader` part returns values from columns all fine, using `_reader.GetValue ()` method. but how do I change the rows? only first row could be read this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You Need to read all the values from the [SQlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) which you received from the [ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader(v=vs.110).aspx) reader.Here I have a created a sample class to give example.

Class defination:

```
public class Sample
{
    public string val1{ get; set; }
    public int val2 { get; set; }
    //Add other fields for data as per ur database

    public Sample(string val1,int val2 )//add further members in constructor
    {
       this.val1 = val1;
       this.val2 = val2;
    }

}


Sample[] allRecords = null;
List<Sample> list = new List<Sample>();
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       list.Add(new Sample(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetInt32(1));
    }

    allRecords = list.ToArray();
}
```

No you dont have to add the var name same as database but in case of datatype you should

Comment: hmmmm... so, I need to make `UrClass` class that contains values of each columns? and maybe obvious, but do I have to name the variables of the class equivalent to the name of the columns in this case?

Comment: @MrSolid51 see Edit

Comment: @MrSolid51 did it help?

Comment: it's a long column, havent finished making them yet, but guess I got ahold of it. thank you.

Comment: @MrSolid51 happy to help sir.

Answer (score 0):

Use read method to iterate over rows.

```
while (_reader.Read())
{
     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));                
}
```